# MATLAB help for cell disruption modelling

Tags: matlab

i keep getting the error "Error using -""Matrix dimensions must agree"
for this piece of code. Can anybody help me and identify where i'm going wrong? I should be getting 8 plots of f vs d.

```
P=500;   
N=1:1:8;   
a=-0.4;  
b=-1;  
Kd=700;  
d50star=(1./(10.^(Kd*(N.^a)*(P-115).^b)))

w0=0.45;  
d=0:0.1:10  
d50N0=5;  
if d50star < 0.33;  
w=(1-(2.3*d50star))*w0  
else   
w=(3.4-(5.5*d50star))*w0  
end

d50=(1-d50star)*d50N0; 

f=1-(1./((1+exp((d-d50)/w))))
```

Comment: Why didn't you simplify the code more and more until you discovered the line(s) that are responsible for your error? As it is this is not useful for anyone else and should be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two errors in the script:

1) in the last line `[f=1-(1./((1+exp((d-d50)/w))))]`

`d` size is 1x101
   `d50` size is 1x8

The size inconsistency is related to the definition of:
   `N=1:1:8;` and
   `d=0:0.1:10`

2) depending on the algoroth, it could be `./w` instead of `/w`

Hope this helps.